# Need recommandations for pattern implementation to inject "processors" into a NuGet from WebApp

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

We are currently developping an internal NuGet package that will send a HTTP Request to another microservice.

Here's a sample of the implementation I am looking for.

- [NuGet package] has a middleware, which is registered in the [WebApp] startup
- [NuGet package] is responsible to create an HTTP request and send it to the microservice
- [WebApp] should be able to create it's own IProcessor that must implement Process() and add any related data it fits required
- [WebApp] should {do something} to "register" it's IProcessor
- [NuGet package] will call the list of registered IProcessor prior to send the request to the microservice

What would be the best way to achieve this (specially the two last items) in .NET core, respecting the Nuget encapsulation.

Thanks :)

Comment: Out of curiosity. if it's internal use only then why are you creating nuget for that?

Comment: We need this lib and many micro service, which are built individually by Jenkins.

Comment: @MihirDave: Creating a NuGet doesn't mean it has to be public. You can easily host your own private NuGet repository, or even get one hosted for you. Azure DevOps, for example, offers private NuGet repositories. NuGet should be used for all shared code, internal or not. If you're still dropping DLLs, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

First, I think it would provide some clarity to realize that it's all just "WebApp". Whether you're using one, many, or no NuGet packages, project references, etc., ultimately it's all just code that's running in your WebApp process.

As such, you can register the `IProcessor` implementation as your would register *any* service:

```
services.AddScoped<IProcessor, WebAppProcessor>();
```

It's unclear what you're ultimately doing here, so depending on that, you can take one of two paths. If there's only one `IProcessor` implementation, then you simply inject that directly into any class that needs it via the class' constructor. That class too would need to be registered with the web app's service collection, so that it participates in the dependency injection process in general.

If you're actually going to have multiple implementations available, then the process is mostly the same, but you'll need to inject `IEnumerable<IProcessor>` instead. The service collection then will inject all registered implementations of `IProcessor`.